# Maven IntelliJ Error Importing Class in Same Package

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, deeplearning4j

I'm working on a project using DeepLearning4J, Maven, and IntelliJ.  I added a user interface class to my package.  However, whenever I try to import a class from the same package into my UserInterface.java class, I receive the following error:

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'stock-analyzer'

Information:javac 1.8.0_121 was used to compile java sources

Information:3/9/17, 8:16 PM - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 2s 143ms

/Users/raulie/CAP5600/stock-analyzer/src/main/java/UserInterface.java

Error:(5, 17) java: package main.java does not exist
Error:(9, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StockAnalyzerBasicForUI
  location: class UserInterface
```

I believe this is a dependency issue with maven, but have been unable to resolve.  I tried "mvn compile" and "mvn clean install" in the project directory (where the pom.xml file is), but receive a similar error like the one shown above.

Below is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>stock-analyzer</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-examples-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <name>Stock Analyzer</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots-repo</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype Nexus snapshot repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <name>Nexus Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
                <version>${nd4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-7.5-platform</artifactId>
                <version>${nd4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-8.0-platform</artifactId>
                <version>${nd4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ND4J backend. You need one in every DL4J project. Normally define artifactId as either "nd4j-native-platform" or "nd4j-cuda-7.5-platform" -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>${nd4j.backend}</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Core DL4J functionality -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-nlp</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- deeplearning4j-ui is used for HistogramIterationListener + visualization: see http://deeplearning4j.org/visualization -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-ui_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Force guava versions for using UI/HistogramIterationListener -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- datavec-data-codec: used only in video example for loading video data -->
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>datavec-data-codec</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <version>${datavec.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Used in the feedforward/classification/MLP* and feedforward/regression/RegressionMathFunctions example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>${jfreechart.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>${jcommon.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Used for downloading data in some of the examples -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>${shadedClassifier}</shadedClassifierName>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/datanucleus/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any insight you can provide into what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you created your intellij project wrong. Maven projects are created with src/main/java as the main source folder.

The fact it says main.java is telling me the way you setup the project it doesn't seem to recognize the source folder properly.